# apxproof changing appendix title

Tags: tables, sectioning, appendices, sections-paragraphs, proof-package

I need to use the apxprrof package because i have proofs that I want to show only in the appendix and this package does exactly what I need.

However, I also need to place some tables (not all) in the appendix, from different sections. If I use the `toappendix' environment the tables go correctly in the appendix but the title of the appendix will be *[LETTER] Proof for Section xy*. Instead, I would like to title the section something else, *[LETTER] Tables for Section xy*, say.

I cannot find a way of doing this. Does anyone have a solution or can advise on another way of achieving this (but still being able to use the apxproof  package)?

A minimal example:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{apxproof}

\begin{document}
\section{Intro}
    This table goes in the appendix.
    \begin{toappendix}
    \begin{table}[h]
      \centering
      \caption{In the appendix}
        \begin{tabular}{lrrr}
                  & A & B & C \\
            M     & 1     & 2     & 3 \\
            N     & 4     & 5     & 6 \\
         \end{tabular}%
      \label{tab:apx}%
    \end{table}%
    \end{toappendix}

\section{Main result}
  See the appendix a proof that $1 + 2 = 4$.
    \begin{appendixproof}
        proof in the appendix.
    \end{appendixproof}
 \end{document}
```

This gives the body as

[image: Body]

and the appendix as

[image]

Comment: `\renewcommand{\appendixsectionformat}[2]{Supplementary Materials for Section~#1 (#2)}` But you don't seem able to vary it.

Comment: @cfr Thanks for the friendly reply. Well, I had tried this command but it changes all titles. I was hoping to be able to change just one one.

Comment: Hence it is a comment and not an answer. I said: 'But you don't seem able to vary it.' Possibly easier to explore alternative approaches to getting the result you want.

Comment: Sure, thanks. Before discovering apxproof I have tried to use clippboard, but it was too cumbersome for my limited latexing. I'll stick to apxproffs and give a generic title to all appendices, as you suggested.